# Cannot read property ... from undefined, when conditionally render a component with ref property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to use a condtion for render a component with a ref prop the react compiler says that it can't find the component with the funtion attached in the ref [image]

this is the code of the container component

```
class Dispersiones extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showDetailDeposito:false
    };
}

onClickRow(row){
    this.setState({showDetailDeposito:true});
    this.refs.detalle.getDataFromTable(row);
}

render(){
    let container={
        height:'100%',
        width:'100%',
        backgroundColor:'cyan',
        position:'relative'
    };


    return(
        <div style={container}>
            <div style={{width:'100%', height:'50%', backgroundColor:'#3b434d', float:'left'}}>
                    { 
                        this.state.showDetailDeposito
                        ?
                        <DetalleDeposito ref="detalle"></DetalleDeposito>
                        :
                        null
                    }
            </div>
            <div style={{width:'100%', height:'50%', backgroundColor:'white', float:'left',overflow:'auto'}}>
                <ListaDepositosPendientes onClickPropTr= {this.onClickRow.bind(this)}></ListaDepositosPendientes>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
}

export default Dispersiones;
```

as you can see the DetalleDeposito tag has a ref attribute but I want to display the component as long as the showDetailDeposito state is set to True, the thing is that when I use the component without the condition it works, but as soon as i put it in the condition it fails.

Hope you can tell me how to render a component with a ref attribute when it depends of a condition when it need to be shown. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is because you are using the same click handler `onClickRow` to both set `showDetailDeposito` to true, and then use the `ref` to call a function. However, because `setState` is asynchronous, the call to the `ref` fails as that component `<DetalleDeposito  />` has not yet been mounted due to `showDetailDeposito` being false.

To fix, you could try using the callback in `setState` to call the `ref` function once the state has been set.

```
this.setState({ 
    showDetailDeposito: true
},
() => this.refs.detalle.getDataFromTable(row)
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what needed